# Very slow parquet reads

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

I'm trying to read parquet files from two different locations A and B. Both of them are parquet files in GCP with approximately same number of columns in the schema (80 - 90, mostly string). B is incredibly small in file size and record count (about 5 orders of magnitude smaller than A). But it takes approximately same time to read from GS as A. I'm wondering why that is.

```
scala> show_timing{spark.read.parquet("gs://bucket-name/tables/A/year=2018/month=4/day=5/*")}
Time elapsed: 34862525 microsecs
res5: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a1: string, a2: string ...     84 more fields]

scala> show_timing{spark.read.parquet("gs://bucket-name/tables/B/year=2018/month=4/day=5/*")}
Time elapsed: 25094417 microsecs
res6: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [b1: string,     b2: string ... 81 more fields]

scala> res5.count()
res7: Long = 2404444736

scala> res6.count()
res8: Long = 98787
```

My spark version is 2.2. I understand that this is not much information to begin with. But I'm not quite sure what else to investigate.

Comment: What's the number of partitions and executors in each case?

Comment: Both same set of gcp n1-standard-8 (8 cores) machines with 60 worker nodes. `--executor-cores` and `--num-executors` are not additionally set.

Comment: What's the number of individual .parquet files in day=5/* ? If there is just one file there for example, only one executor would be reading it despite you have many of them available. On the other hand, if there are thousands of small files, the cost of opening them is may be too high and it is worth to consolidate them in a small number of larger files  when saving the data to this partition. Also, take a look in Spark UI whether all executors are utilized equally during the reading stage.

Comment: For case B, Its one file per hour. So 24 per day. Each file is less than 2MB in size. In case A, per hour, its about 200 files each of 150 MB each. The difference is rather large. I'm gonna increase executor per core and see.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that spark is not actually *reading* the data when it executes the `read.parquet` operation, so the read operation takes roughly the same time. `read` is *lazy*, that is, data is accessed only when you execute an action (like `count`). I bet the two count operations don't take the same time!

When `read` is executed, it only reads the metadata of the parquet file to figure out the schema, so the file size doesn't matter that much.

Have a look at transformations vs actions in spark. Some operations trigger computation (and consequently I/O to materialize the rdd), some don't: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-operations

Comment: This was the first and most obvious explanation of course. But if you notice the time itself, its disproportionately large. When I read one month worth of data, this command takes ~25 minutes to execute. Even if spark goes through all the files to figure out the schema with its lazy read, it is doing so only with 30 x 24 files. Each file about 2MB. That's nothing. The cluster is also huge - with about 360 cores. The time just doesn't make sense. Hence I'm looking for alternate explanations.